# Old TV episode that ends with a plane that lands in a remote (as I recall) airstrip with just a skeleton pilot

Tags: story-identification, tv

There are no passengers, just the pilot and the plane seems to be one that is not flown anymore, but appears brand new.

The show is in black & white (as I remember) and I honestly thought it was an episode of *One Step Beyond*, though I cannot find ANY episodes in any of the five seasons that it fits into. Nothing in *The Twilight Zone* or *The Outer Limits* either.

I KNOW I saw this episode from SOME series years ago but cannot find it anywhere! What brought it to mind was the story about Flight 513, the Lockheed Airplane that supposedly landed 37 years later with 92 skeletons on board. The passage of time in the 513 story is similar to the amount of time that passes in the one I am referring to.

This is driving me nuts because I would love to see this "show" again and share it on YouTube in my previous comment about it. I am looking like a crazy person right now because I cannot find it.

Is this a real, true blue example of "The Mandela Effect?" Help!!!!

Comment: Could it be this? https://www.kindertrauma.com/name-that-trauma-m-w-on-a-skeleton-glider-picnic/

Answer (score 5):

This sounds very much like what LogicDictates linked to, an episode of *One Step Beyond* in which a glider-plane that has gone missing returns with a skeletonized pilot behind the yoke. While we do not see the skeleton pilot at the end, the narrator does a pretty good job describing it.

Here is the episode in question: [Reunion episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpBSmXMWijo&t=1434s)

Comment: 'Twas James McLeod who provided the link, in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275526/old-tv-episode-that-ends-with-a-plane-that-lands-in-a-remote-as-i-recall-airst#comment759841_275526). I just edited the question.

Comment: This theme specifically about planes shows up a lot, with the "twist" being the crew are ghosts and years later the wreck of their ww2 bomber is discovered and it is finally then that they realize how long they have been stuck in the desert. Not this story, but I am assuming that so many men fought in the skies in ww2 that this general idea is easy to confuse with other episodes on other shows.

Answer (score -1):

One step beyond: Season 2, Episode 10. It's on Youtube, but the final scene I remember - the skeleton pilot in the aviator's gear - isn't included. I've found references online to the last scene being of the skeleton, though. I remember seeing this in Sunday afternoon reruns back in the early 1970s...

Comment: That episode of _One Step Beyond_ was already named in [Cassfrank's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/275560/122024). As such, this answer seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Yes, However,it adds the information that the skeleton pilot may have been originally shown but edited out for later airings.